# How to transfer a project from ClearCase to TFS?

Tags: tfs, clearcase-ucm

Excuse me for the novice question :blush:

How do I detach a project from ClearCase in order to add it to a TFS source control system?

Comment: So now instead of one CSCM it's another CSCM. Net gain -> a different logo.

Comment: @user2864740 - a couple of things: 
1. Not always it's the programmer's choice, some people have a boss telling them to do this (TFS) and not that (CC)
2. I personally don't like the fact that CC plug in for VS does not support lots of functionality - you actually have to open the CearCase Explorer and Object Explorer in order to acheive stuff. I don't get it - if you already make a plug in, what don't you give some usability (it's not a dirty word)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's silly but here's what I needed to do -

1. Open each of the csproj files
2. For each one, remove the xml nodes starting "Scc" (like SccProjectName, SccAuxPath, SccProvider etc) it seems they were the ones bothering the Visual Studio.
3. Reload the projects and add them to desired TFS workspace

Additional Steps that may need to be done:

- Open the .sln with a texteditor and delete the entire section about source control.
- In Visual Studio go to Extras -> Options... -> Sourcecontrol and change the plug in to TFS

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to do whats called a "tip" migration.  This just means grab a copy of your source code from ClearCase to your harddrive.  Then add all the files to TFS.  This will bring over the latest version of your code, but will not bring over the history.

If you want to do a migration that brings over history you will need to use a tool such as the TFS Integration Platform.  The ALM Rangers have produced a connector for ClearCase and a bunch of training and videos on how to perform a migration that can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/07/27/getting-started-with-ibm-rational-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-migrations.aspx

Comment: Dylan Smith - When I grab a copy of the source and (try to) add the files to TFS I get: 
"The project MyLovelyProject is under source control. An error occured regustering this projcet with source control. It is reconneded that you do not make any changes to this project.

What did I miss? It looks like I need to remove the reference to CC first...