# Issues removing sourcecontrol bindings

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, clearcase

I want to migrate a lot of projects from Clear Case to TFS2015 via the "add to source control" option of VS2015.
I started out with this [How to transfer a project from ClearCase to TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968510/how-to-transfer-a-project-from-clearcase-to-tfs) SO question and its answers.

This works out fine for most of the cases but in some cases the clear case reference seems undeletable. Whenever i go right click on my solution and want to add it to source control it gives me a clear case error "Project must be in a view". When i inspect File -> Sourcecontrol -> Change source control i can see no binding to clear case and when i first opened the solution i took the option "permanently remove all source control bindings from this project"

So my question is, are there any further references to a solutions/projects source control other than the "scc" nodes in the .proj files and how can i delete them so that i can add it to my TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer myself:

- First: do the same thing you did with .proj files with the .sln and remove the entire globalsection about sourcecontrol.
- Second: go in Visual Studio to Extras -> Options... -> Source Control and there change the plug in from clearcase to TFS.
- Finally: profit

I didn't bother checking this before because like i said this occured randomly and I don't know why when i started to migrate the plug in was always selected as TFS and then, after some projects, changed to clearcase... anyways i will let this question up here for someone who may run into the same issue since i did not find very much online about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, it said i can do this after 2 days, forgot about it